# webRTC: How to update the video stream from the callee's end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webrtc

I am working on WebRTC and I have a scenario in which I have to update the stream from the callee's end.

I have tried the replace track method but later on, I found that it works only for the initiator of the call (i.e. caller).

I have done the search for it on the internet but didn't found any exact solution. Can anybody help me that how I should proceed?

A demo example will be appreciated.

The whole scenario is like this:

1) A initiates the call using the WebRTC process with B.
2) Now A and B both will have the ability to share their screen.
3) A is able to update his/her stream that is being sent to the user B using the WebRTC replaceTrack method. It's working fine.
4) When user B tried to update the stream that is being sent to the User A using WebRTC replaceTrack method, nothing happens.

Is there anyway so that we can update the stream of the user B?

Thank you!

Comment: you should show us some code or something, this is too vague without something tangible

Comment: Thank you for your response duxfox.  Actually, The code was too complex so, I didn't put it here. But I have updated the question. Please check if it can clarify the question.

Comment: you expect the solution for a problem with complex code to be found without looking at the code?